# Remove a certain commit as if it never happened

Tags: git

I have a log which looks like

> c2ba4f3cfd3e8b29e634b41d7178ffe38f8c9f0a version 0.1
>   d825b48fe86107c3842f62c9e9bc5f290a2c2475 test2
>   0a06037c3c29a0c9446707e884d9b2777336db59 test
>   c7453d959fc86d2868076b3900e0fd1ed63e2709 begin

All has been pushed to my origin server already but I want to merge the commits in such a way that it appears that the only one I have ever made was the one with comment `version 0.1`. The server must reflect the commits merge when I push it too.

In short, I want the repository to have a single commit with the contents of the one I named.

I have tried rebase all the day and have not been able to get the desired result. How can I do this?

Comment: You don't. "All has been pushed to my origin server". That means don't do it. I guess in theory everyone might have based their code on `c2ba4f3cfd`, but what if they branched off of `d825b48fe86` or need that commit for some reason?

Comment: @alternative You are wrong, I **will** do it. Also, who are you talking about? the only one with access to that repository is me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obligatory caveat: Changing history that has already been pushed to a remote repository can be a massive headache for anyone else using the repository.

An interactive [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) will get you there.

```
# start an interactive rebase onto the parent (~) of 'begin'
git rebase -i c7453d9~
```

The interactive rebase will pop you into an editor that looks like this:

```
pick c7453d9 begin
pick 0a06037 test
pick d825b48 test2
pick c2ba4f3 version 0.1
```

**If you want to keep all the changes from all the commits but make them look like one commit**, change it to this:

```
reword c7453d9 begin
fixup 0a06037 test
fixup d825b48 test2
fixup c2ba4f3 version 0.1
```

`reword` will prompt you to change the commit message (change it to 'version 0.1'), and `fixup` will pull all the content from the commit into the previous commit. The end result will be a single commit containing the content from all four.

Another way to accomplish the same thing:

```
pick c7453d9 begin
fixup 0a06037 test
fixup d825b48 test2
squash c2ba4f3 version 0.1
```

`squash` pulls the content of a commit into the previous commit, but lets you change the commit message (in this case, to 'version 0.1').

**If you want to completely discard changes from first three commits and only keep changes from the last**, change the rebase lines to this:

```
pick c2ba4f3 version 0.1
```

Essentially, delete the first three lines. The end result will be just the 'version 0.1' commit, without any content from the prior commits.

Once you've modified the history, you'll need to force the [push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to your remote with `--force`.

Comment: With a `git rebase -i c7453d9~` I get `fatal: Needed a single revision`, `invalid upstream c7453d9~`. Just in case, a `git status` says `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should have the 'version 0.1' commit checked out, and you want to rebase on top of whatever the commit before 'begin' is: `git rebase -i <commit before 'begin'>`.

Comment: @ellotheth Regarding the difference between `fixup` and *deleting the line*, you should speak of "changes introduced by" a commit, not the "content of" a commit. The *content of* a commit is a snapshot of the filesystem at that time. If we delete the lines `pick 0a06037 test` and `pick d825b48 test2` and keep the line `pick c2ba4f3 begin`, the filesystem content after rebase will not be the exact same as it was at commit `c2ba4f3`; instead, it will look like the filesystem at `c7453d9` plus the changes introduced between `d825b48` and `c2ba4f3`. Fixups *would* make it look just like `c2ba4f3`.

Comment: [cont'd] I'm sure you understood that already, but the terminology could be improved in your answer.

Comment: @kostmo I'll clarify, but with a caveat: Colloquially, commits are already a conceptual shorthand for 'the changes introduced by' (c.f. `git cherry-pick`). For history manipulation, it's more useful to abstract commits as diffs from the parent state than as diffs from the parent PLUS the parent state. I don't think "content from the last commit" can be convincingly misunderstood as "filesystem state at the last commit", particularly since the first bold section explicitly references "all the changes from all the commits".

Answer (score 0):

You can erase the commits in between.

```
git reset --mixed c7453d9
git checkout c2ba4f3cf -- .
git add -A
git commit -C c2ba4f3cf
```

Comment: Can I somehow erase the first one too?